# iOS app using previously selected localization instead of Base

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

Im using localized strings with `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()` in my project. Supposed that when a user switches to the one of unsupported languages, Base localization is used. But it works wrong: previously selected localization is used instead of the Base.

I've already tried to remove and add base localization.

May by somebody faced this problem before?

My project settings:

[image: Project settins]

Settings of one of the strings files:

[image: File settings]

Info.plist:

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: This is most likely correct behaviour – go to the Settings app -> General -> Language & Region. Since iOS 8 there has been the concept of 'Preferred languages', which is an ordered list of preferred localisations. What's happening is it is falling back to the user's second preferred language. Once all the languages have been exhausted, only then will it resort to base.

Comment: I was not providing a solution, I was providing an explanation. Can you describe the exact problem that you are seeing (which languages you expect to show, and which language is actually showing), as well as a screenshot of Settings -> General -> Language & Region?